# Flask - different static folders if localhost of server

Tags: python, angularjs, heroku, flask

I'm using Flask and deploying my app on Heroku. My app directory is like this:

```
myapp/
    app/
        static/
        dist/
        __init__.py
    run.py
```

But I'm working with grunt and angular.js, then when I'm developing I want to use the static folder and when I deploy I want to use the dist folder.

**routes**

```
@app.route('/')
def root():
    return send_from_directory(app.config['STATIC_FOLDER'], 'index.html')
```

**config**

```py
with app.test_request_context('/'):
    host = request.host

if host == 'localhost' or host == '127.0.0.1':
    STATIC_FOLDER = os.path.join(basedir, 'app/static')
    app.static_folder = STATIC_FOLDER
else:
    STATIC_FOLDER = os.path.join(basedir, 'app/dist')
    app.static_folder = STATIC_FOLDER
```

Trying it like this doesn't work. It still uses the index.html that is inside the static folder and not the one which is inside dist folder.

Answer (score 1):

I'd just use two separate configuration files (like `debug.py` and `production.py`) with `STATIC_FOLDER` variable set for `app/static` and `app/dist` respectively.

A [How to Structure Large Flask Applications](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-structure-large-flask-applications) suggests you to use `run.py` for debugging purposes and `config.py` for production purposes; you could separate it this way.

It's not clear how do you use your config. Where is it located, in `run.py`?

The simpliest example:

```
# run-debug.py
import os

from myapp import app


if __name__ == '__main__':
    basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
    app.config['STATIC_FOLDER'] = os.path.join(basedir, 'myapp/static')
    app.run()
```

And a `run-production.py` which is basically the same, but with just the path changed (set to `'myapp/dist'`). Please note that I made it just for testing purposes; you should feed a heroku's gunicorn server with an app object to deploy, so there would be a `"deploy-heroku.py"` file, which contains something like that:

```
from myapp import app  # import flask's app object
app.config['STATIC_FOLDER']  = 'myapp/dist'  # set the STATIC_FOLDER parameter to whatever you need in a Heroku instance
```

and then, in Heroku's gunicorn/procfile config, link it to the deploy-heroku's app object, which has `STATIC_FOLDER` overridden.

I'm also not sure that you assign `STATIC_FOLDER` configuration parameter properly.
You do:

```
app.static_folder = STATIC_FOLDER
```

and then you try to get it from `app.config['STATIC_FOLDER']`. It may be a reason it doesn't work. Perhaps try writing directly to the `app.config['STATIC_FOLDER']` itself?